# T-SQL query that only selects records where an entity has highest priority over other entities

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a complicated SQL query I'm having difficulty solving. I could do it in C# but I would be bringing a massive amount of data back from the database (800K+ records). So, it's important to solve this within the database, only returning the final records that meet the criteria. Hopefully I can communicate effectively what the requirements are.

I have a few tables in the mix I have abbreviated for simplicity. The relationships between tables should be extremely obvious.

```sql
Asset (
    AssetId INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    SerialNumber NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Description NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)

AssetDealer (
    AssetDealerId INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    AssetId INT NOT NULL,
    DealerNumber NVARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    RelationshipTypeId INT NOT NULL
)

RelationshipType (
    RelationshipTypeId INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    Description NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PriorityRank INT NOT NULL
)
```

Dealer A may have sold the asset to the consumer. Dealer B may have installed the asset for the consumer. Dealer C may have a service contract with the consumer to perform the maintenance. i.e. A sales only dealer, an independent installer and a service only dealer.

The priority rank column of the relationship type table defines the order of precedence. A lower priority rank is actually higher precedence (think first place, second place, third place). That precedence is Service, Installer, Sales or essentially, who "serviced" the consumer last.

The query needs to return a list of assets associated with a specific dealer. Here's the tricky part. If asset 123 follows the scenario above where there's a separate dealer for each stage (sales, install, service), asset 123 cannot be included for dealers A or B, it can only be included for dealer C since they're the servicing dealer and they have highest priority.

However, if asset 123 doesn't have a service agreement with a dealer (only sales and installation dealers are associated with the asset), then asset 123 is included for dealer B but not included for dealer A. Likewise, if asset 123 hasn't been installed yet, only then will it be included for dealer A.

Keep in mind that Dealer A could do all three stages or just 2 of the three (i.e. sales + service). In such case asset 123 is included for dealer A because dealer A is the servicing dealer and would then have higher priority over dealer B who performed the install.

In summary, any one asset can only appear in the results of the query for a single dealer. There should never be a case where two dealers are able to see the same asset. In essence, finding all assets associated with a specific dealer then removing any assets where another dealer has a higher priority relationship.

I've tried a few ways of tackling this but I've come up empty. Thanks in advance.

I have a complicated SQL situation I'm having difficulty solving. I could do it in C# but I would be brining a massive amount of data back from the database (800K+ records). So it's important to solve this within the database, only returning the final records that meet the criteria.

I have a few tables in the mix I will abbreviate for simplicity:

```
Asset (
    AssetId INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    SerialNumber NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Description NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)

AssetDealer (
    AssetDealerId INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    SerialNumber NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    DealerNumber NVARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    RelationshipTypeId INT NOT NULL
)

RelationshipType (
    RelationshipTypeId INT IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    Description NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PriorityRank INT NOT NULL
)
```

Dealer A may have sold the asset to the consumer. Dealer B may have installed the asset for the consumer. Dealer C may have a service contract with the consumer to perform the maintenance. i.e. A sales only dealer, an independent installer and a service only dealer.

The priority rank column defines the order of precedence. A lower priority rank is actually higher precedence (think first place, second place, third place). That precedence is Service, Installer, Sales. Or essentially, who "serviced" the consumer last.

The query will return a list of assets associated with a specific dealer. Here's the tricky part. If asset 123 follows the scenario above where there's a separate dealer for each stage (sales, install, service), asset 123 would not appear for dealers A or B, only C since they're the servicing dealer and they have highest priority.

However, if asset 123 doesn't have a service agreement with a dealer (only sales and installation), then asset 123 would appear for dealer B but not for dealer A. Likewise, if asset 123 hasn't been installed yet, only then would it appear for dealer A. Keeping in mind that Dealer A could do all three stages or 2 of the three (i.e sales + service).

In summary, any one asset will appear in the results of the query for only a single dealer. So finding all assets associated with a specific dealer then removing any assets where another dealer has a higher priority relationship.

| AssetId | SerialNumber | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | Widget |
| 2 | 234 | Spinner |
| 3 | 345 | Poster |
| 4 | 456 | Toy |

| AssetDealerId | AssetId | DealerNumber | RelationshipTypeId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | A | 3 |
| 2 | 1 | B | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | C | 1 |
| 4 | 2 | A | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | A | 2 |
| 6 | 2 | A | 3 |
| 7 | 3 | A | 3 |
| 8 | 3 | B | 2 |
| 9 | 3 | A | 1 |
| 10 | 4 | A | 3 |

| RelationshipTypeId | Description | PriorityRank |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Service Dealer | 1 |
| 2 | Installer | 2 |
| 3 | Sales Dealer | 3 |

Query results for dealer A

| AssetId | SerialNumber | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2 | 234 | Spinner |
| 3 | 345 | Poster |
| 4 | 456 | Toy |

Query results for dealer B = NO ASSETS

Query results for dealer C

| AssetId | SerialNumber | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 123 | Widget |

Comment: Consumable sample data, and expected results, will help us help you here.

Comment: I figured so. I'm about done drawing up a set of data.

Comment: you should be able to use row_number to calculate what you want. Something like: select * from (select *, row_number() over(partition by ass.assertID ORDER BY PriorityRank ) AS sort  from Asset  ass inner join AssetDealer d ON d.assetid = ass.assetid inner join RelationshipType  rr ON rr.RelationshipTypeId  = d.RelationshipTypeId) x where x.sort = 1

Comment: @siggemannen I've tried this but it doesn't do the exclusion part

Comment: you should post it to the question :)

Comment: Oh ok, the problem is that you're looking at things from the *dealer*'s point of view. Then yeah, it will be a bit more complicated

Comment: @siggemannen yeah I was hunting for that tiny edit link. Finally found it.

Comment: @siggemannen yeah I know. I generally can solve most problems in SQL. This one has me stumped. One large dealer has 820K+ records it's associated with but it's mainly sales. Only about 5000 should actually show up.

Comment: I suppose 'priority' is itself not a column, but in future making it so would make like much easier.  I realize it is not trivial, and sometimes not a good idea, to add a column to an existing database table, so this is just an idea.

Comment: @JosephDoggie That's the entire point behind the RelationshipType table. It does exactly what you suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, the query i wrote worked fine for me after some adjustments:

```sql
select *
    into #asset
    from (
        VALUES  (1, 123, N'Widget')
        ,   (2, 234, N'Spinner')
        ,   (3, 345, N'Poster')
        ,   (4, 456, N'Toy')
    ) t (AssetId,SerialNumber,Description)
    
    select *
    into #assetDealer
    from (
        VALUES  (1, 1, N'A', 3)
        ,   (2, 1, N'B', 2)
        ,   (3, 1, N'C', 1)
        ,   (4, 2, N'A', 1)
        ,   (5, 2, N'A', 2)
        ,   (6, 2, N'A', 3)
        ,   (7, 3, N'A', 3)
        ,   (8, 3, N'B', 2)
        ,   (9, 3, N'A', 1)
        ,   (10, 4, N'A', 3)
    ) t (AssetDealerId,AssetId,DealerNumber,RelationshipTypeId)
    
    select *
    into #relationshipType
    from (
        VALUES  (1, N'Service Dealer', 1)
        ,   (2, N'Installer', 2)
        ,   (3, N'Sales Dealer', 3)
    ) t (RelationshipTypeId,Description,PriorityRank)
    
    
    select * from (
        select ass.*, d.DealerNumber, rr.Description AS relationship
        ,   row_number() over(partition by ass.assetID ORDER BY PriorityRank ) AS sort 
        from #Asset ass
        inner join #AssetDealer d
            ON d.AssetId = ass.AssetId
        inner join #RelationshipType rr ON rr.RelationshipTypeId = d.RelationshipTypeId
    ) x 
    where x.sort = 1 
    and DealerNumber IN ('A', 'B', 'C') -- here you set which dealer you're looking for
```

I first prepare correct asset overlay by only taking the top most prioritized dealer per asset. Then i check which dealer i'm looking for.

Comment: I suspect this will give better performance than my answer.

Comment: I need to add an index but it seems to be working. There's some data quality issues but I think I have a workaround.

Comment: In the partition by I needed to add d.DealerNumber as it was excluding too many records
row_number() over(partition by ass.assetID, d.DealerNumber ORDER BY PriorityRank ) AS sort

Comment: Are you sure? Then it will not return correct values in my opinion. If three different people did different relationships it will include too many people

Comment: The whole point was to get one dealer per asset, no?

Comment: With added dealernumber you will get one asset per dealer's relationship, so one asset will return multiple dealers

Answer (score 1):

I think you first need to work out which Relationship is priority for each asset, then you can join in in the rest of the details. Something like this:

```
WITH PriorityAssetRelationship as (
  SELECT 
    AssetDealer.AssetId, 
    MIN(RelationShipType.PriorityRank) MinRank
  FROM 
    AssetDealer
    JOIN RelationshipType 
      ON RelationShipType.RelationShipTypeId = AssetDealer.RelationShipTypeId
  GROUP BY
    AssetDealer.AssetId
)
SELECT 
  Asset.AssetId,
  Asset.SerialNumber,
  Asset.[Description]
FROM
  Asset
  JOIN AssetDealer 
    ON Asset.AssetId = AssetDealer.AssetId
  JOIN RelationshipType 
    ON RelationShipType.RelationShipTypeId = AssetDealer.RelationShipTypeId
  JOIN PriorityAssetRelationship 
    ON AssetDealer.AssetId = PriorityAssetRelationship.AssetId 
    AND RelationshipType.PriorityRank = PriorityAssetRelationship.MinRank
WHERE
  AssetDealer.DealerNumber = 'A'
```

Full test script:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION

CREATE TABLE Asset (
    AssetId INT NOT NULL,
    SerialNumber NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    Description NVARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE AssetDealer (
    AssetDealerId INT NOT NULL,
    AssetId INT NOT NULL,
    DealerNumber NVARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    RelationshipTypeId INT NOT NULL
)

CREATE TABLE RelationshipType (
    RelationshipTypeId INT NOT NULL,
    Description NVARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    PriorityRank INT NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO Asset
VALUES
(1, '123', 'Widget'),
(2, '234', 'Spinner'),
(3, '345', 'Poster'),
(4, '456', 'Toy')

INSERT INTO AssetDealer 
VALUES
(1, 1, 'A', 3),
(2, 1, 'B', 2),
(3, 1, 'C', 1),
(4, 2, 'A', 1),
(5, 2, 'A', 2),
(6, 2, 'A', 3),
(7, 3, 'A', 3),
(8, 3, 'B', 2),
(9, 3, 'A', 1),
(10, 4, 'A', 3)

INSERT INTO RelationshipType
VALUES
(1, 'Service Dealer', 1),
(2, 'Installer', 2),
(3, 'Sales Dealer', 3);

WITH PriorityAssetRelationship as (
  SELECT 
    AssetDealer.AssetId, 
    MIN(RelationShipType.PriorityRank) MinRank
  FROM 
    AssetDealer
    JOIN RelationshipType 
      ON RelationShipType.RelationShipTypeId = AssetDealer.RelationShipTypeId
  GROUP BY
    AssetDealer.AssetId
)
SELECT 
  Asset.AssetId,
  Asset.SerialNumber,
  Asset.[Description]
FROM
  Asset
  JOIN AssetDealer 
    ON Asset.AssetId = AssetDealer.AssetId
  JOIN RelationshipType 
    ON RelationShipType.RelationShipTypeId = AssetDealer.RelationShipTypeId
  JOIN PriorityAssetRelationship 
    ON AssetDealer.AssetId = PriorityAssetRelationship.AssetId 
    AND RelationshipType.PriorityRank = PriorityAssetRelationship.MinRank
WHERE
  AssetDealer.DealerNumber = 'A'

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```